# I have a large Image, but i need to use that same image just half the size and retain image quality

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am having troubles using Images for retina display. I use `drawImage`. I have a set of large images(canvas drawn) and I want to use them but just half the size and making them smaller increase image quality.

How does one do this? This is an off screen canvas.

Comment: convert your using imagealpha application and then use it

Comment: Surely I should be able to do this in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can oversample an image (increasing its resolution) by setting its CSS size smaller than the canvas elements size:

**Larger html canvas element:**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=300></canvas>
```

**Smaller CSS styling (results in 2x oversampling):**

```
#canvas{ width:300px; height:150px; }
```